# Color Interpolation

Tags: colors, interpolation, polynomial-math, blending

Okay, so I'm looking at a typical color chooser and it looks something like this:

[image]

If we deal with only highly saturated colors, the blending pattern behaves like this:

```
R 255  
G 0  
B 0  

R 255  
G 0 -> 255  
B 0  

R 255  
G 255  
B 0  

R 255 -> 0  
G 255  
B 0  

R 0  
G 255  
B 0  

R 0  
G 255  
B 0 -> 255  

R 0  
G 255  
B 255  

R 0  
G 255 -> 0  
B 255  

R 0  
G 0  
B 255  

R 0 -> 255  
G 0  
B 255  

R 255  
G 0  
B 255  

R 255  
G 0  
B 255 -> 0  

R 255  
G 0  
B 0
```

Is it possible to define an interpolating function f which takes a value from 0 to 1 and produces a color on this spectrum (where 0 and 1 correspond to the left and right hand sides of the spectrum posted above)?  I only care about highly saturated colors (One component is always 255.).  Also, I notice that this pattern blends from R to G to B.  However, is there also a similar function which blends between cyan, magenta, and yellow?  And while this is not correct, if f(0) produced cyan and f(1) produced yellow, then f(0.5) would produce a green color similar to the one you might achieve if you mixed two paints.

I hope this makes sense.  Please feel free to have me clarify anything.  Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV might help. Where the 0-1 range you wanted is 0-360 degrees.

Comment: @Pod: That's exactly what he needs - should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color explains HSL for the scarce CSS3 web and includes a simple HSL->RGB implementation.

Comment: Yes, that's right!  Now, is there a scheme that blends more like the electromagnetic spectrum (ROYGBIV)?

Comment: Oops!  That's not what I meant.  That's what HSL Does.  I'm actually wanting something like a painter's color wheel.

Comment: Ah, nevermind again.  They're almost the same.  HSL is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

HSL might be better than RGB on some occasions but [HCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_color_space) is the best visually. It is computationally more expensive but you could use it as an intermediate step. The standard interpolation function is always:

```
C(x) = (1.0 - x) * color_1 + x * color_2, where x in (0.0, 1.0)
```

You want to do this for every component, where **red green** and **blue** or **hue saturation** and **value**.

```
R(x) = (1.0 - x) * color_1.red + x * color_2.red
G(x) = (1.0 - x) * color_1.green + x * color_2.green
B(x) = (1.0 - x) * color_1.blue + x * color_2.blue
```

Where each component can be either normalised (from `0.0` to `1.0`) or straight `0.0` to `255.0`.

When using RGB values the intermediate results might not what you want to achieve visually. The numerical results however should always be. In other words, the R G and B values should smoothly move from the start to the end numbers. Visually however this might result in some unwated grays and this is where HCL shines.

Check out [this](http://blog.karmadust.com/interpolating-uicolors/) tutorial where I go into more depth.